# MYSQL: Can I use outer query table alias inside subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is my query:

```
select uact.onAssetID as AssetID, a1.value as AssetValue,
uact.CommentID, a2.value from useractivity uact inner join asset a1 on
uact.onAssetID=a1.ID inner join (select * from asset inner join
useractivity on uact.onAssetID=a1.ID group by a1.ID limit 3) a2 on
uact.CommentID=a2.ID;
```

> ```
> Error: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'uact.onassetID' in 'on clause'
> ```

What I am trying do?
Imagine there is Table1 with 10 student names, now there is Table2 which has 10 records(rows) for each of the student present in table1. If I try to use join on both tables, it will return 100 records(10 records for each student). What I want is, to limit the result returned by join by 5 records per students
So, I should get 5 records per student hence 50 output rows

**Table Structure(asset):**

```
ID | TypeID | CategoryID | Worth | isActive 
| CreationDate | ExpiryDate Value | AssetOwner
```

**Table Structure(useractivity)**
`| ID | ActivityTypeID | UserID | Time | onAssetID | CommentID`

Notes:
1) ID for both table is a primary key
2) onAssetID and commentID in useractivity are foriegn keys referring to ID in asset Table

Feel free to let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 2):

> What I am trying do? Imagine there is Table1 with 10 student names,
>   now there is Table2 which has 10 records(rows) for each of the student
>   present in table1. If I try to use join on both tables, it will return
>   100 records(10 records for each student). What I want is, to limit the
>   result returned by join by 5 records per students So, I should get 5
>   records per student hence 50 output rows

Answer for this:-
Table1(studentid,.......) 
Table2(id,.........,studentid)

```
select s.*,temp.* from (SELECT @var:=if(@var2= a.studentid,@var+1,1) sno, @var2:= studentid, a.*
FROM Table2 a,(select @var:=0) b, (select @var2:=0) c 
order by studentid) temp, Table1 s where temp.sno<=5;
```

> For your table structures:- Table Structure(asset): ID | TypeID |
>   CategoryID | Worth | isActive  | CreationDate | ExpiryDate Value |
>   AssetOwner  Table Structure(useractivity): | ID | ActivityTypeID |
>   UserID | Time | onAssetID | CommentID

```
select s.*,temp.* 
from 
     (SELECT @var:=if(@var2= a.onAssetID,@var+1,1) sno, @var2:= onAssetID, a.*
      FROM useractivity a,(select @var:=0) b, (select @var2:=0) c 
      order by onAssetID) temp, asset s 
where temp.sno<=5;
```

Comment: If you want 3 rows per join replace 5 with 3.

Comment: It worked, after some tweaking Final QUery: (Please remove '' from @)    select uact.onAssetID as AssetID, a1.value as AssetValue, uact.CommentID, a2.value 
from asset a1 inner join (SELECT '@'var:=if('@'var2= a.onAssetID,'@'var+1,1) sno, '@'var2:= onAssetID, a.*
FROM useractivity a,(select '@'var:=0) b, (select '@'var2:=0) c
order by onAssetID) uact on uact.onAssetID=a1.ID inner join asset a2 on uact.CommentID=a2.ID where uact.sno<=1;

Comment: Reading & writing the same variable in a select statement is undefined in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

you call them like a2.column_name as you have called that query a2

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so, but only if you place it in the correct segment.  And be aware that doing so in a FROM subquery could seriously hamper performance.

Anyway, your problem appears to be that you're referencing `uact` and `a1` where they're not defined, which is a syntax violation.  Add aliases to the subquery, and if needed reference the outer query in your `WHERE` clause.

Change

```
(
 SELECT * 
 FROM asset 
 INNER JOIN useractivity ON uact.onAssetID=a1.ID 
 GROUP BY a1.ID 
 LIMIT 3
) a2
```

to

```
(
 SELECT ID, Value 
 FROM asset AS a
 INNER JOIN useractivity AS ua 
   ON ua.onAssetID=a.ID 
) a2
```

(Note that your `LIMIT` clause would apply to the *ENTIRE* query, and a2 would only return three rows in total, rather than three rows per join.)

Comment: But I want 3 rows per join, for that I believe I need to reference outer query table inside inner query.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is some way to use outer query table alias inside subquery uning **lateral** join
https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-lateral-join/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).