# how to select first two rows from each group

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi We have 3 Table of a `music` which is something like this in MySql :

**1st Table** :

the first table is for `playlist` table where `music playlist` is exist.

```
playlistId           playlistTitle          categoryId

1                    hello                  0
2                    wow                    0
3                    wi-fi                  0
4                    awesome                0
5                    sixer                  1
6                    four                   1
7                    boundary               2
```

**2nd Table :**

2nd table is for `songRelation table where every playlist is associated with thier song

```
playlistId            songId

1                     4
1                     3
1                     43
1                     57
1                     98
2                     56
2                     67
2                     90
2                     78
3                     98
3                     78
3                     89
43                    90
```

**3rd Table :** 
the 3rd table is for `song` table where song detail exist

```
songId                songTitle

4                     hello
3                     real hero
43                    singalone
57                    awesom
98                    really
78                    sakaka
98                    shikwa
89                    moha
90                    hello2
67                    Sneh
```

actually i want to get result something like this :

```
playlistId  songId    categoryId songTitle

1           4         0          hello
1           3         0          real hero
2           56        0          singalone
2           67        0          Sneh
3           78        0          sakaka
3           98        0          Shikwa
```

where the every `playlistId` will be with their first 2 `songId` and with their `categoryId` and also with `songTitle`.

Comment: use inner select query in a query refer this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Comment: What defines order in `song` table, so that we can pick *first 2* `songId`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Order Will `assending` `songId`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL: Can I use outer query table alias inside subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008392/mysql-can-i-use-outer-query-table-alias-inside-subquery)

Answer (score 3):

You can use variables:

```
SELECT playlistId, songId, categoryId, songTitle
FROM (
  SELECT p.playlistId, s.songId, p.categoryId, s.songTitle,
         @r := IF (@pid = p.playlistId,
                   IF (@pid := p.playlistId, @r+1, @r+1),
                   IF (@pid := p.playlistId, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM playlist AS p
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r:=0, @pid:=0) AS vars
  INNER JOIN songRelation AS sr ON p.playlistId = sr.playlistId
  INNER JOIN song AS s ON sr.songid = s.songid
  ORDER BY p.playlistId, s.songId ) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
```

Variable `@r` is used to enumerate records within each `playlistId` slice. Using this in an outer query, we can easily get 2 records per `playlistId` slice.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eda7/5)

Comment: @Grorgos Betsos How can i get how many `songId` is exist in a single `playlistId`

Comment: @rahul You can use a sub-query for this. But that's a different question.

Comment: @Grorgos Betsos Can you embed this subquery in above above what have you answered.

Comment: @Gorgos Besos If you will say then i can edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using `JOIN`, try this code:-

```
SELECT playlist.playlistid, songRelation.songId, song.songTitle
FROM playlist JOIN songRelation JOIN song
WHERE playlist.playlistId=songRelation.playlistId 
AND songRelation.songId=song.songId LIMIT 2
```

you can add the category table and use the same way to get the result table you need, you can also save this query as a virtual table `VIEW` by writing this code before the code:-

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
```

Edit:-

```
SELECT playlist.playlistId from playlist INNER JOIN( SELECT playlist.playlistId, songRelation.songId, song.songTitle
    FROM playlist JOIN songRelation JOIN song
    WHERE playlist.playlistId=songRelation.playlistId 
    AND songRelation.songId=song.songId 
    GROUP BY playlist.playlistId LIMIT 2)
    WHERE playlist.playlistId=songRelation.playlistId
```

Comment: this only gives two item, because you limited the data as `limit 2` but i want actually is every `playlistId` with `2` `trackTitle`.

Comment: The above edit query telling that every table has it's own schema. can you solve that.,, then plz edit them.

Comment: @rahul what do you mean that every table has it's own schema? what is the result you get with this query?

Comment: and also can you tell me How can i get how many `songId` is exist in a every `playlistId`

Answer (score 0):

Please try it, as it is not tested with data, so if you get any issue then create an sqlfiddle so that I can solve the issue.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT pl.playlistid, sng.songId, sng.songTitle,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @category != pl.playlistid THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @category := pl.playlistid AS play_list
    FROM playlist AS pl 
    JOIN songRelation AS sr ON sr.playlistid=pl.playlistid 
    JOIN song AS sng ON sng.songid=sr.songid  
        JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @category := '') r     
      ORDER BY pl.playlistid,sng.songid) X
      WHERE x.rank<=2
```